# two method with same name and different parameter of two classes that implements on interface

Tags: java, android

I have on interface 'A' and two class that implements 'A' :

```
Interface A {}

class B implements A{ String name;}
calass C implements A{ String lastName;}
```

I have two method in another class like 'K' whit same name that their methods are class A and B :

```
class k {
        public void del(B b){
           delete(b.name);
        }
        public void del(C c){
           delete(c.lastName);
        }
    }
```

in another class :

```
class G{
  K k=new k();
  public void delete (A a){
  k.del(a);
}
```

and i want to instantiate class G an pass an instantiate of class B or C and if parameter of delete method is instance  of class B delete name and if is instance of class C delete last Name like this :

```
G g=new g();
B b=new b();
g.delete(b)
```

how can do that ?

Comment: and by "_delete name_" you mean??

Comment: i want if I pass instance of class C to delete method it deletes c.lastName and if I pass instance of class B to delete method it deletes b.name automatically without I define different delete method with different name  and check which instance of A interface

Comment: i think there's no way to automatically downcast one object to another without checking its type (using `instanceof`)